# Transmit javascript variable to a plugin function (async URL)

Tags: javascript, jquery

For My projet i need to know how i can transmit some variables to a async url. The plugin I use is a simple popover that call a URL to fetch html data and show the result.

I need to use **$(this)** because i have many URls with the same class. I must transmit the data-type (ex: picture) and the id of the product (data-id).

My link = `<a href="#" class="product" data-type="picture" id="1">Check this out</a>`

What i want to do (but it doesn't work) :

```
$('.product').webuiPopover({
    var productType = $(this).data('type');
    var id = $(this).data('id');
    type:'async',
    url:'/api/popover/'+ productType +'/'+id
});
```

Is it possible ? How i can do that ?

Note : here is the plugin I use (github : sandywalker/webui-popover)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to add variable then you can do it like:

```
$('.product').each(function(i,t){
    var t = $(t);

    t.webuiPopover({
        type:'async',
        url:'/api/popover/'+ t.data('type') +'/'+ t.data('id')
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to initialize webuiPopover for each `.product` element individually. Do something like this:

```js
$('div').each(function(index, el){
  $(el).webuiPopover({
   title: $(el).data('foo') // Direct access to the data attributes of this element
  })
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/jquery.webui-popover/1.2.5/jquery.webui-popover.min.js"></script>

<div data-foo="First title">Hello</div>
<div data-foo="Second title">Goodbye</div>
```